# WKWebView does not load NSURLs created with fileURLWithPath:relativeToURL:

Tags: ios, nsurl, wkwebview

I noticed that `WKWebView` does not load (via `loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:`) an NSURL created with `fileURLWithPath:relativeToURL:`.

I created a github repo showing this behavior: https://github.com/davidkraus/WKWebViewNSURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can just pass the absolute string of the url to a new NSURL.

```
var theURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "www/index.html", relativeToURL: folder)
// create a new NSURL
theURL = NSURL(string: theURL.absoluteString)!
webView.loadFileURL(theURL, allowingReadAccessToURL: theURL)
```

Comment: no you are doing wrong.use urlWithString. fileURLWithPath searches the url in the file system.